# Changing majors for masters degree specifically in Europe

Tags: masters, changing-fields, europe

I have done my bachelors in Electronics & Communications Engineering from India and I am currently working as a software developer with 1.5 years of experience.

I would like to do my masters from Europe but either in Computers or Software Engineering field. Is it possible to change from a field like electronics to software specifically in Europe ( preferably Germany or Netherlands).

I know it is quite common in US but I am not able to figure this out about European universities.

Comment: Not an answer to this question, but in this answer I wrote how to apply if you don't have all the required undergrad courses because you come from a different major. http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/16013/what-is-the-best-way-to-take-missing-courses-before-applying-to-ms/18194#18194

Answer (score 2):

I will put a bit of a damper on cleverrainbow's and deloz's enthusiasm.

First, there are two kinds of masterks programs in Germany: consecutive and non-consecutive. Non-consecutive programs are open to anyone who meets the general admissions criteria, while consecutive master’s programs require that a student have a degree in the same discipline as the original degree, and enough overlap between the curricula at whatever school the student did their bachelor’s at compared to the bachelor’s at the school with the master’s program. If the difference is too large (more than about one semester’s worth), you can be refused admission.

Secondly, if you are coming from outside the EU, the university must recognize your undergraduate degree as being at a school comparable to the one to which you are applying.

Finally, in the event you are admitted, you may find that you need to get approval from the study advisor of the major you wish to pursue, and possibly have to obtain credit for *each* individual course you want to transfer from *each* individual instructor responsible for the respective courses at the new university. Moreover, if you are missing too many credits, your application for transfer will likely be declined, as there are generally minimum limits for how many credits can be transferred from the bachelor's degree.

Comment: Additionally, you will need to find out whether your bachelor degree is recognized in the country where you want to pursue your master degree. Also, for many studies in Germany you will be required to pass a German language test (you do not need to be fluent, though). In the Netherlands there are also many degrees that are taught in English (I don't know to which extent they exist in Germany).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I didn't quite understand what you mean by obtaining credit for each course I want to transfer from. Also, when I send my completed application it gets either selected or rejected by the admissions committee. Where does the process  of contacting the study advisor comes into the picture?

Answer (score 1):

I only know about Germany, and as @deloz already mentioned it is definitely possible.

Most Universities will look at what you have already studied during your bachelor's degree and sometimes require you to take extra classes during or before your master's degree in order to catch up to their standards.

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely possible in germany, but depends on the university.

But why change? 
I studied electrical engineering in my b.sc. and and m.sc in munich.

My masters studies had a strong focus on the software part of electrical engineering (security / machine learning).

So its definitely possible to do a master focused on software with a electronics background in germany.