# Am I taking the Right steps at Switching from Geoinformatics Bsc to Information Technology Msc?

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, united-kingdom, germany

I am a Bsc degree holder in Geoinformatics from Nigeria intending to apply for Msc in Information Technology program in Germany, looking at the prerequisite its entirely a different ball game. So I decided to take some training for IT certificate courses like Network+, Cyber Ethical Hacking (CEH) and hoping to do Cisco certified Network Association (CCNA) and even planing on learning German language soon. 
My question is will these certification acquisition give me a boost for admission to study Information Technology in Germany or anywhere in the UK.

Comment: Related: http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/16013/what-is-the-best-way-to-take-missing-courses-before-applying-to-ms/18194

Answer (score 1):

This heavily depends on the program you are applying for. Usually (in Germany) they require you to have an *equivalent* Bachelor to what they offer as Bachelor in the field, i.e., Information Technology in your case. Whether a Bachelor is *equivalent* is typically decided case by case. The whole procedure and detailed requirements are described in the *Zugangsordnung* of the faculty.

Since you are a student from a non-EU country there are most likely more requirements you need to fulfill, e.g., assessment of the German university entrance qualification, language requirements, visa, etc. You should get in contact with the *international office* of the university as soon as possible.

Comment: Interesting scenario. Smaller institutions in the U.S.A would usually be happy to accommodate scenarios like this, but of course, one would have to usually be self-financed, as is the case for most M.S. IT programs here in the USA.